# Strip Data from a jQuery Variable, Increment the Number that's left, Put the stripped data back in the Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to write a script in jQuery that first, takes src of an image tag (with ID "#image").

Then strips away the first part of the image path ("images/big/") and the image extension (".jpg"). This leaves just the image name, which is just a number (ranging from 1 to 7).

Then, increments that number by 1.

Then puts image path and the image extension (the stuff removed at the beginning) back in the proper place. Then assign this new path to the img tag (with ID "#image")

Essentially the script is meant to increment the number that is the image's name.

This is the code I managed to write:

```
var imagePath = ( $("#image").prop("src") );
    var imagePath = imagePath.replace('images/big/', '');
    var imagePath = imagePath.replace('.jpg', '');
    var imagePath = imagePath++;
    var imagePath = "images/big/"+imagePath+".jpg";
    $("#image").attr("src", imagePath);
```

Sadly, however, it does not work, its seems to just return a value of "NaN". Any help you can give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: +1 for well mannered question with source and output example.

Comment: If it returns `NaN`, most likely you're not filtering all non-number characters from the `src` string. Could you provide us with a full image tag's source or try to reproduce the scenario on http://jsfiddle.net please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have too much code to replace a single number.

```
$("#image").attr("src", $("#image").attr("src").replace(/\d/, function(s) {
    return +s+1;
}));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmx2E/1/)

Or a more sturdy version (makes sure the number is followed by `.jpg` and may accept more than single-digit numbers):

```
$("#image").attr("src", $("#image").attr("src").replace(/(\d+)\.jpg/, function(s, m) {
    return (parseInt(m, 10)+1) + '.jpg';
}));
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xmx2E/1/)

[`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) parses a string into an integer with the radix/base specified -- `10` corresponds to decimals. It's done so the JS engine doesn't assume that a number should be an octal if it starts with `0` for example. Well, always when you use decimals, use `parseInt(myNumber, 10)` to be sure that it's parsed as decimal integer.

The [`.attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) you should be familiar with, it retrieves the given HTML attribute when passed 1 argument and sets the given attribute when passed 2 arguments. So basically, I'm setting the `src` attribute with the same `src` after having the `replace` method applied to it.

The [`string.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) method takes 2 arguments, in this case I'm using a regex ([Regular Expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)) to match digit characters (`\d` is a character class representing `[0-9]`) followed by the literal `.jpg` string and replacing them with the matched number incremented by 1.

The function object in the 2nd parameter of the `replace` method takes as arguments the whole match (`s`) followed by N number of capturing groups (`m` = `\d+` = one or more digit characters). As I only have one [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), I give 2 parameters to the function so I can use the captured group and increment it inside the function object, returning the incremented number + `.jpg` to replace the `number.jpg` in the original source.

And for the reason your code was not working, my only guess is that you weren't stripping out all non-number characters from the string, hence when the `++` increment operator tries to force a typecast it just returns a `NaN`, as the given string fails to be parsed as integer. With my replace method, it takes only the number from the string and increments it, independently of the rest of the string.

---

**Edit:**

I found the main problem of your code, `$("#image").prop("src")` retrieves the **FULL** URL of the image, that is why, as my paragraph above implies, you weren't removing all non-number characters and it failed to evaluate as integer. Replacing that `.prop` with `.attr` may allow your original code to work as well.

Though you shouldn't assign a variable to itself after using the post-increment operator `++` and declaring the same variable name in the same scope more than once is considered bad practice (most JS interpreters ignore re-declarations but it is sloppy coding).

So another corrected version of the code:

```
var imagePath = $("#image").attr("src"); //use .attr as .prop returns full URL
imagePath = imagePath.replace('images/big/', '').replace('.jpg', '');
imagePath++;
imagePath = "images/big/"+imagePath+".jpg";
$("#image").attr("src", imagePath);
```

Comment: Thanks Fabrício, the second of those blocks of code works brilliantly. I'm a little new to jQuery. Could you explain to me how the (/d+) works in the replace function, and how the parseInt syntax works? Many Thanks.

Comment: @baxterma gimme a minute 'cause there's a lot to write still. `=]`

Comment: @baxterma I'm not very good explaining, but I've put a good deal of effort. Tell me if you need more specific explanation in any of the topics. `=]`

Comment: I think I get it, so the \d is just representing any number between 0 and 9. The replace is looking for [any number].jpg in the string it's passed. It then passes that to the parse function, which takes the number then increments it. The replace then reattaches the .jpg to the incremented number and it is returned to the src of the img tag. The advantage over my code is that yours can look for any number, and will intelligently filter the number. What I don't get is, how does it filter the "images/big"? P.S. You're much better at explaining that you think! :)

Comment: Exactly! `:)` `images/big` is kept as it is part of original string, my `replace` function only replaces the `[number].jpg` part, the rest is kept as it was before. `=]`

Comment: @baxterma Imagine that instead of erasing all non-number characters from the string and building a new one from scratch as you were doing initially, I'm merely working in the part which needs to be changed by `replace`'ing it. `=]`

Comment: Ah! So your code is not 'taking the src out of the img, editing it, and puting it back', like mine did. It is just looking at the src, and 'editing it' live?

Comment: @baxterma Depends how you look at it. First I obtain the `src` with `attr` then edit it with `replace` and put it back (with the first `src`), the only difference is that I'm not storing it in any variable.

Comment: In case you need to store the current number in a var, I can arrange for that as well. `=]`

Comment: No I don't, :). What you showed my was exactly what I was I needing to do (it's for an image slideshow/lightbox type thingy). :) I understand what you code does now, thanks very much for your very thorough answer! :) One last, small question though :) Can you recommend and good jQuery books/resources for beginners (like my self)? :)

Comment: I personally learned mostly by myself and with friends, but let me see. If you're visual like me, I'd try browsing youtube for some jQuery tutorials, they explain from the very basic to more advanced stuff. Then we have the [tag page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jquery/info) which has some good info and links. `=]`

Comment: Ok, I'll have a look. :) Many thanks for your help, I really appreciate it! :D

Comment: @baxterma If you can mark this as the accepted answer before you leave I'd glad, no problem man. `=]`

Comment: @baxterma I was just doing some testing and I found the main problem with your original code - check my updated answer when you have time. `=]`

Comment: Thats wonderful, thanks. I was wondering why my code wasn't working as expected, and assumed it was some stupid mistake somewhere (as it turned out, it was!). Thanks again! :) I you have a spare moment, I'd really appreciate your expertise on another jQuery/Javascript related question I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777615/disable-a-href-when-an-img-src-is-equal-to-a-specific-value-with-jquery :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem actually is that you are creating a new variable when you are incrementing the number. This line is wrong:

> var imagePath = imagePath++;

This will work better:

```
var imagePath = ( $("#image").prop("src") );
imagePath = imagePath.replace('images/big/', '');
imagePath = imagePath.replace('.jpg', '');
imagePath++;
imagePath = "images/big/"+imagePath+".jpg";
$("#image").attr("src", imagePath);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H3VQV/12/)

Comment: always remember to specify your radix ie parseInt(imagePath, 10); or use Number(imagePath);

Comment: newCount++ is enough, no need to assign it back to itself :)

Comment: I'm most certainly sure that the increment operator would force a typecast to integer ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MevR4/)), but if this works..

Comment: Can't believe I didn't spot that earlier...I've updated my answer.

Comment: extra `var` keywords don't really matter, they just assure that the following var name belongs to the local scope. IMO OP has a problem calling the function or something.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yeah, that's true. If this doesn't work for him I don't know what's going on =)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use javascript's [parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert the string to number and then increment it.