# Disable a href when an img src is equal to a specific value with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an img tag (id "image"). The src of the img is assigned using jQuery, (there are separate buttons for each image than can be displayed). There is a button to advance to the next picture (think of it as a slideshow). The 'next' button is just an anchor tag with a href to another jQuery function.

When the final picture is the one occupying the src of the img tag, I would like to remove the href of the anchor tag (the 'next' button). If it is not the final picture that is the src of the img tag, I want the 'next' button to by 'active' (have the href to the other jQuery Function).

When the page loads, the img tag doesn't have a src.

I wrote the following code, thinking it would work:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var src = ($("#image").attr("src"));
    if  (src == "images/big/7.jpg") {

        $("#next").attr("href","");

    } else {

        $("#next").attr("href", "javascript:nextImage()");

    }
});
</script>
```

Sadly it doesn't. It does not disable the 'next' button when the img has a src of "images/big/7.jpg". I am also sceptical as to whether this script would continue to check the src of the img if the 'next' button had been disabled. For example: if I advanced to the last image, and the 'next' button got disabled (href removed), if I went back a couple of pictures, would the 'next' button be re-enabled (href re-added)?

Any help you can give as to why this isn't working and what I should do to make it would would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

EDIT: The next image code, plus some more.

```
 <script style="text/javascript">
function nextImage() {
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#image").attr("src").replace(/(\d+)\.jpg/, function(s, m) {
    return (parseInt(m, 10)+1) + '.jpg';
}));}
</script>
```

Also, the code for the buttons, and the img tag. The previousImage(), lastImage(), etc. are just modifications of nextImage(). Cheers.

```
<img id="image" src=""></img>
        <div class="imageToolbar">
            <a id="first" href="javascript:firstImage()"></a>
            <a id="previous" href="javascript:previousImage()"></a>
            <a id="next" href="javascript:nextImage()"></a>
            <a id="last" href="javascript:lastImage()"></a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sup man, could you post the `nextImage` function's code as well? (presumably I know what it is from your last question, but it's good to have a compilable example to test)

Comment: +1 for the whole example, here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cZYS7/). Also, it's relatively hard to disable a link, you can change the CSS to make it look different and do nothing when users click on it but it'll still be clickable. Wouldn't it be easier to use buttons instead?

Comment: Yeah, I just want it to do nothing when the user clicks on it. I thought setting the href to "" would do that? I never though about making them buttons :). If I changed the anchor tags to buttons, how should I modify my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the page is always loaded with the first image displaying, I adapted your function slightly to work with buttons, using the [disabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLInputElement) property accordingly:

**HTML**

```
<img id="image" src="images/big/1.jpg">
<div class="imageToolbar">
    <button id="first" disabled="disabled">First</button>
    <button id="previous" disabled="disabled">Prev</button>
    <button id="next">Next</button>
    <button id="last">Last</button>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
function changeImage(arg) {
    $("#image").attr("src", $("#image").attr("src").replace(/(\d+)\.jpg/, function(s, m) {
        var min = 1, //configure these
            max = 7, //values
            $lower = $('#first, #previous'),
            $higher = $('#next, #last');

        m = parseInt(m, 10);

        if (arg == 'next') {
            m++;
            $lower.prop('disabled', false);
            if (m == max)
                $higher.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else if (arg == 'previous') {
            m--;
            $higher.prop('disabled', false);
            if (m == min)
                $lower.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else if (arg == 'first') {
            m = min;
            $higher.prop('disabled', false);
            $lower.prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else if (arg == 'last') {
            m = max;
            $higher.prop('disabled', true);
            $lower.prop('disabled', false);
        }

        return m + '.jpg';
    }));

    //you can remove the next line on the production server:
    console.log('Current image: ' + $('#image').attr('src'));
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#first').click(function(){ changeImage('first'); });
    $('#previous').click(function(){ changeImage('previous'); });
    $('#next').click(function(){ changeImage('next'); });
    $('#last').click(function(){ changeImage('last'); });
});
```

### [*jsFiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/cZYS7/4/)

But well, if you're working on a Slideshow plugin, why reinvent the wheel? You may as well look at ready goodies such as [jQuery Camera Slideshow](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/).

Comment: Fantastic, thank you so much! :) The reason I decided to reinvent the wheel, and not use something like Camera, or lytebox is because I needed a little more customisability. The site I'm building is build around pop-overs, and the pop-overs contain a little more than just images. The slideshow is, comparatively speaking, a small piece of the puzzle. :) Thanks so much for all your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code will run once, and only once, when the page first loads. You need to run the code every time the image changes in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

It is considered bad practice to use javascript-hrefs. Since you use jQuery anyway, you could just hook to the [click-event](http://api.jquery.com/click/) in your buttons and then call `nextImage()` from JavaScript code. Something like this:

```
$("#next").click(function (e) {
    // If this was an a-element, prevent going to that page
    e.preventDefault();

    var src = $("#image").attr("src");
    if  (src != "images/big/7.jpg") {
        nextImage();
    }
});
```

Now this code runs every time the user clicks on the `#next` element.

Comment: it's generally not a good idea to name a parameter `event` as this shadows the global `window.event`, that's why you see just `e` in most jQuery handler functions.

Comment: I knew there was something why I never named it `event`. Had forgot that. Fixing code now.

Answer (score 0):

On document ready, put your code in a function like this

```
function imageCheck() {
    var src = ($("#image").attr("src"));
    if  (src == "images/big/7.jpg") {
         $("#next").attr("href","");
    } else {
        $("#next").attr("href", "javascript:nextImage()");
    }
 };
```

And call this function from your nextImage() function. So every time nextImage function runs, your imageCheck() function will check for the value of image src and display the href appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use an array as a placeholder for your images to the src attr?

In this way, you can always keep track of which image is being viewed currently, which is positioned at the last, and so on! I think this looks much better rather than having to compare the last one to a specific string name/image file!